# Enviar Adjunto en Mail Automático Ayuda plz

Tags: php, mail

tengo el siguiente problema, y es que no se como puedo enviar en la función mail de php un fichero adjunto que es un pdf que previamente se sube por un formulario 
Este es el formulario:

```
 <form action="#" id="curriculum" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="color: #737373">
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                <label for="curname">Nombre</label>
                <input type="text" id="curname" name="curname" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                <label for="curemail">Email</label>
                <input type="email" id="curemail" name="curemail" class="form-control" >
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                <input type="checkbox" id="privacidad2" >
                <label style="font-size: 12px" for="privacidad2" class="text-">He leido y acepto la <a href="privacidad.php">Politica de privacidad</a> </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="curdoc">
                    <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload text-danger"></i> <span class="text-white">Seleccionar Curriculum</span>
                </label>
                <input name="curdoc" id="curdoc" type="file" hidden>
            </div>
            <div style="margin-left: 10px" class="input-group-append">
                <button class="btn btn-primary text-white" type="button" id="sendcurriculum">Enviar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Y este el php con el que envió el mail que llega perfecto pero sin adjunto

```
<?php

//vars
$subject = "Entrega de curriculum";

$from = $_POST['curemail'];
$to =$_POST['to'];

//Obtener datos del archivo subido
$file_tmp_name    = $_FILES['curdoc']['tmp_name'];
$file_name        = $_FILES['curdoc']['name'];
$file_size        = $_FILES['curdoc']['size'];
$file_type        = $_FILES['curdoc']['type'];
$file_error       = $_FILES['curdoc']['error'];

if($file_error > 0)
{
    die('Error al subir el archivo. No se adjunto ningun archivo');
}

//Leer el archivo y codificar el contenido para armar el cuerpo del email
$handle = fopen($file_tmp_name, "r");
$content = fread($handle, $file_size);
fclose($handle);
$encoded_content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));

$boundary = md5("pera");



//data
$msg = "CURRICULUM VITAE: "."<br>\n";
$msg = "NOMBRE: "  .$_POST['curname']    ."<br>\n";
$msg .= "EMAIL: "  .$_POST['curemail']    ."<br>\n";

//Adjunto
$msg .= "--$boundary\r\n";
$msg .="Content-Type: $file_type; name=".$file_name."\r\n";
$msg .="Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$file_name."\r\n";
$msg .="Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
$msg .="X-Attachment-Id: ".rand(1000,99999)."\r\n\r\n";
$msg .= $encoded_content;

//Headers
$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
$headers .= "From: <".$from. ">" ;


//send for each mail
mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers);
if (mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers)){
    return true;
}
else{
    return false;
}

?>
```

Este es un trozo de la respuesta que me da... me lo da codificado

```
--Message-Boundary
Content-type: Binary; name=
Content-Transfer-Encoding: BASE64
Content-disposition: attachment; filename=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```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como no conseguí usar `mail()` de php para enviar un adjunto al final use la clase `phpMailer` dejo el ejemplo aquí por si a alguien le surge la misma duda

```
<?
  // primero hay que incluir la clase phpmailer para poder instanciar
  //un objeto de la misma
  require "includes/class.phpmailer.php";

  //instanciamos un objeto de la clase phpmailer al que llamamos 
  //por ejemplo mail
  $mail = new phpmailer();

  //Definimos las propiedades y llamamos a los métodos 
  //correspondientes del objeto mail

  //Con PluginDir le indicamos a la clase phpmailer donde se 
  //encuentra la clase smtp que como he comentado al principio de 
  //este ejemplo va a estar en el subdirectorio includes
  $mail->PluginDir = "includes/";

  //Con la propiedad Mailer le indicamos que vamos a usar un 
  //servidor smtp
  $mail->Mailer = "smtp";

  //Asignamos a Host el nombre de nuestro servidor smtp
  $mail->Host = "smtp.hotpop.com";

  //Le indicamos que el servidor smtp requiere autenticación
  $mail->SMTPAuth = true;

  //Le decimos cual es nuestro nombre de usuario y password
  $mail->Username = "micuenta@HotPOP.com"; 
  $mail->Password = "mipassword";

  //Indicamos cual es nuestra dirección de correo y el nombre que 
  //queremos que vea el usuario que lee nuestro correo
  $mail->From = "micuenta@HotPOP.com";
  $mail->FromName = "Eduardo Garcia";

  //el valor por defecto 10 de Timeout es un poco escaso dado que voy a usar 
  //una cuenta gratuita, por tanto lo pongo a 30  
  $mail->Timeout=30;

  //Indicamos cual es la dirección de destino del correo
  $mail->AddAddress("direccion@destino.com");

  //Asignamos asunto y cuerpo del mensaje
  //El cuerpo del mensaje lo ponemos en formato html, haciendo 
  //que se vea en negrita
  $mail->Subject = "Prueba de phpmailer";
  $mail->Body = "<b>Mensaje de prueba mandado con phpmailer en formato html</b>";

  //Definimos AltBody por si el destinatario del correo no admite email con formato html 
  $mail->AltBody = "Mensaje de prueba mandado con phpmailer en formato solo texto";

  //se envia el mensaje, si no ha habido problemas 
  //la variable $exito tendra el valor true
  $exito = $mail->Send();

  //Si el mensaje no ha podido ser enviado se realizaran 4 intentos mas como mucho 
  //para intentar enviar el mensaje, cada intento se hara 5 segundos despues 
  //del anterior, para ello se usa la funcion sleep 
  $intentos=1; 
  while ((!$exito) && ($intentos < 5)) {
    sleep(5);
        //echo $mail->ErrorInfo;
        $exito = $mail->Send();
        $intentos=$intentos+1;  

   }


   if(!$exito)
   {
    echo "Problemas enviando correo electrónico a ".$valor;
    echo "<br/>".$mail->ErrorInfo;  
   }
   else
   {
    echo "Mensaje enviado correctamente";
   } 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tengo un script en mis sistemas que envía unos pdf diariamente a algunas personas. La siguente función recibe como parametros 2 arrays con las direcciones `$mail_from` y `$mail_to`, un asunto `$subject`, el mensaje `$message`, y un array (opcional) con los nombres de los adjuntos `$files`. La misma función puede enviar correos con y sin adjuntos, porque algunas personas solo reciben un reporte (sin adjuntos) de que el correo con adjuntos se envió a los que le deberían llegar.

```
$mail_from = array('from_mail'=>'tu_correo@tudominio.com', 'from_name'=>'Tu Nombre');
$mail_to = array('to'=>'destinatario@sudominio.com', 'cc'=>''); // cc es opcional
```

Y la función es

```
function send_email($mail_from, $mail_to, $subject, $message, $files=array()) {
    // Enviar correo con la instruccion "mail()" nativa de PHP [ - Solo Windows - ]
    // En el futuro se recomienda cambiar esto a phpmailer() u otra libreria más robusta y multiplataforma.
    $headers = "To: ". $mail_to['to'] . "\r\n";
    $headers .= ($mail_to['cc'] != '') ? "Cc: ".$mail_to['cc']."\r\n" : '';
    $headers .= "From: ".$mail_from['from_name']." <".$mail_from['from_mail'].">"."\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    if(count($files) > 0) {
        // Si hay elementos para adjuntar
        $semi_rand = md5(time());
        $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\r\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"" . "\r\n";
        // multipart boundary
        $msgdata = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n\r\n";
        $msgdata .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
        $msgdata .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\r\n";
        $msgdata .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
        $msgdata .= $message . "\r\n\r\n";
        $msgdata .= "--{$mime_boundary}\r\n";
        // preparing attachments
        for($x=0; $x<count($files); $x++) {
            $file = fopen($files[$x], "rb");
            $data = fread($file, filesize($files[$x]));
            fclose($file);
            $chunk_data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
            $msgdata .= "Content-Type: {\"application/octet-stream\"};\r\n" . " name=\"$files[$x]\"\r\n" .
            "Content-Disposition: attachment;\r\n" . " filename=\"$files[$x]\"\r\n" .
            "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n" . $chunk_data . "\r\n\r\n";
            $msgdata .= "--{$mime_boundary}\r\n";
        }
    } else {
        // Si no hay elementos para adjuntar, enviar un correo en texto plano
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\r\n";
        $msgdata = $message;
    }
    // send email
    mail($mail_to['to'], $subject, $msgdata, $headers);
}
```

Si necesitas que el texto sea en HTML pues cambias las partes que dice `text/plain` a `text/html`.

Comment: Buenos dias primero muchas gracias por el aporte, no consigo adaptarlo a mi proyecto, ya que lo mio suben un archivo que es el curriculum y se me deberia enviar por correo a mi, me puedes ayudar a adaptarlo?